# Changing the font in my ggplot dendrogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, cluster-analysis, dendrogram

I tried plotting a colorful dendrogram to include in my thesis, and it all works just fine apart from one thing: changing the font. I plotted many dendrograms before, and changing the font was never a problem, but in this code it suddenly is... I probably tried to write family="serif" in about any space possible, but idoes not work. My code:

```
dencw3m <- as.dendrogram(aggl.clust.manhattan.ward.cw3m)

dendro.col.cw3m <- dencw3m %>%
  set("branches_k_color", k = 5, value =   c("blue", "red", "limegreen", "gold", "darkorange")) %>%
  set("branches_lwd", 0.6) %>%
  set("labels_colors", 
      value = c("darkslategray")) %>% 
  set("labels_cex", 0.5)

gg.cw3m <- as.ggdend(dendro.col.cw3m)

ggplot(gg.cw3m, theme = theme_minimal()) +
  labs(x = "Fall", y = "Homogenität", title = "Dendrogramm cw3m", family = "serif", cex = 0.4, hang = -1)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Explicitly list all non-base R packages you are using.

Comment: What options are available to you via `grSoftVersion()`, and posting results and operating sys, R-version,, will make helping easier.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the `dendextend` package, so not sure whether it offers an easy option to set the font family via an argument. However, as the final result is a `ggplot` object, one option to achieve your desired result would be to manually set the `family` parameter of the `geom_text` layer used to add the labels.

Making use of the default example from `?ggdend`:

```r
library(dendextend)
library(ggplot2)

dend <- iris[1:30, -5] %>%
  dist() %>%
  hclust() %>%
  as.dendrogram() %>%
  set("branches_k_color", k = 5, value =   c("blue", "red", "limegreen", "gold", "darkorange")) %>%
  set("branches_lwd", 0.6) %>%
  set("labels_colors", 
      value = c("darkslategray")) %>% 
  set("labels_cex", 0.5)

ggd1 <- as.ggdend(dend, theme = theme_minimal())

p <- ggplot(ggd1)
```

Having a look at the layers of `p` we see that the `geom_text` is the third layer:

```
p$layers
#> [[1]]
#> mapping: xend = ~xend, yend = ~yend, colour = ~col, linetype = ~lty, size = ~lwd, x = ~x, y = ~y 
#> geom_segment: arrow = NULL, arrow.fill = NULL, lineend = square, linejoin = round, na.rm = TRUE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = TRUE
#> position_identity 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> mapping: colour = ~col, shape = ~pch, size = ~cex, x = ~x, y = ~y 
#> geom_point: na.rm = TRUE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = TRUE
#> position_identity 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> mapping: label = ~label, colour = ~col, size = ~cex, x = ~x, y = ~y 
#> geom_text: parse = FALSE, check_overlap = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#> position_identity
```

Hence, to switch the font family we could set the `family` argument of the `aes_params` of this layer like so:

```
p$layers[[3]]$aes_params$family <- "serif"
p
```

[image]